# Pass the path of an opened file to a batch file

Tags: java, file, batch-file, file-association

If I link a batch file as a file association for a certain file extension, then I can use it to pass arguments to the main function of the Java program. How do I get the path of the opened file as argument to use it then in Java? I want to make it possible to directly open files created and used by my Java program.

MyFile.extension > Open with > MyBatch.bat

MyBat.bat

```
java -jar test.jar thisIsWhereThePathBelongs
```

test.jar main function

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0]); // thisIsWhereThePathBelongs
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This more or less works, I can get the argument to the main function output, but how do I store the path of the opened file as an argument? `java -jar test.jar thePath` --> `thePath` when I print the first index of my args array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your batch (or .cmd) file to pass on the arguments it receives when called via `Open with ...` or as file extension association, you need to ensure the argument `%1` is passed to Java:

**MyBat.bat**

```
@echo off
java -jar your.jar your.className %1
```